# Task page is not opening when clicking on Log a call button

Tags: tasks

when an end user is clicking on Log a call button from case, he/she is getting 500 status error code return instead of new task page where as if i check in URL, it is pointing to a visualforce page which redirects a page. The same is not happening with system admin.

What could be the issue here?